# Find Control in asp:repeater on button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list inside a asp:repeater item template.
how can I get its value on button click event.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="WorkflowListAfter" onitemcreated="WorkflowListAfterItemCreated">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlWorkflowMembers" runat="server" DataTextField="MemberName" DataValueField="MemberID">
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected DropDownList ddlWorkflowMembers = new DropDownList();
protected void WorkflowListAfterItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ddlWorkflowMembers = (DropDownList) e.Item.FindControl("ddlWorkflowMembers");
}
protected void BtnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (ddlWorkflowMembers.SelectedItem == null) return;
}
```

the code above is working at first time but after postback ddlWorkflowMembers is always null expersion.

Comment: Are you doing `WorkflowListAfter.DataBind()` after postback?

Comment: no. just on WorkflowListAfterItemCreated() { ... }

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming that `BtnSave` is also inside the repeater.

You get the `RepeaterItem` by casting the button's [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx). Then you can use `FindControl` to get the reference to your `DropDownList`:

```
protected void BtnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var btn =  (Button)sender;
    var item = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
    var ddl =  (DropDownList) item.FindControl("ddlWorkflowMembers");
    // ...
}
```

If the button is outside of the repeater and you want to save all items, you need to loop through all:

```
protected void BtnSaveClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    foreach(RepeaterItem item in WorkflowListAfter.Items)
    {
        var ddl =  (DropDownList) item.FindControl("ddlWorkflowMembers");
        // ...
    }       
}
```