# Retrieving the text property of a label inside a repeater asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

[Here's how the repeater looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyiWT.png) I am an amateur as far as asp.net is concerned. What I'm trying to do is that I have a repeater control in my page that is set to show data upon selection of an item in a radio button list.

Upto this point its all good, next what I have to do is:

I want to retrieve the text of lblId when the buttonbook is clicked in repeater. I have no idea how to achieve this. Any help would be much appretiated.

Here's the code:

```
                       <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
               DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceHolidays" Visible="False" >
               <ItemTemplate>
               <table style="border: 1px solid #A55129; background-color: #FFF7E7">
               <tr>
               <td style="width: 200px">
               <asp:Image ID="imgEmployee" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("h_description")%>'
               runat="server" />
               </td>
               <td style="width: 200px">
               <table>
               <tr>
               <td>
               <b>Id:</b>
               </td>
               <td>
               <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("h_id") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
               </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td>
               <b>Name:</b>
               </td>
               <td>
               <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("h_name") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
               </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td>
               <b>Duration:</b>
               </td>
               <td>
               <asp:Label ID="lblGender" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("h_duration") %>'>
               </asp:Label>
               </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td>
               <b>Price:</b>
               </td>
               <td>
               <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("h_price") %>'>
               </asp:Label>

               <asp:Button ID="Buttonbook" runat="server" Text="Button" 
               OnClick = "Buttonbook_Click" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("h_id") %>' />
               </td>
               </tr>
               </table>
               </td>
               </tr>
               </table>
               </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: See [find-control-in-asprepeater-on-button-click-event](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10880297/3711928).

Comment: Smbdy plz hlp with my questions, as i said im a amateur im really stuck here.

Comment: Thanks for ur hlp evrybdy, Finally figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

specify if you need a specific row or the entire list, in the case you need to check all items you can use a foreach cicle in your buttonclick event

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
{
     var MyLabel = (Label) item.FindControl("lblId");
     string labelText = Mylabel.Text;
}
```

Comment: Sry if this is a noobish question bt it says 'mylabel does not exist in current context'

Answer (score 0):

You have to write below logic in your button click event

```
 var button = (Button)sender;
 var item = (RepeaterItem)button.NamingContainer;
 var lblName = item.FindControl("lblName") as Label;
```

Comment: This means lblName holds the value for the lblName control? And if i write "Response.Write(lblName);" Will this display the value in lblName?